# Why push method modify all my object items?

Tags: javascript, object, push

**I have this request service:**

*// request.service.ts*

```
export class RequestService {

  public pendingRequests: Request[];

  constructor() {
    this.pendingRequests = [];
   }

  public insert(request:Request):void{

    this.pendingRequests.push(request);
  }

}
```

**I insert requests to pending requests object from my component:**

```
    ...
    this._requestService.insert(this.request);
    const pendingRequests = this._requestService.pendingRequests; 
    console.log(pendingRequests);
```

***PendingRequests throws correctly the updated object for first time, when i push second item each item get updated***

How can i push new request without modify all other items?

Comment: you're probably **reusing** `this.request` in the code you have not shown - perhaps `this.pendingRequests.push({...request});` - though, that only fixes shallow "re-use" - it'd make more sense to know what `this.request` is, and how you use it - note: it's nothing to do with the `push` method, it's how you're mis-using `this.request`

Comment: You right. I was **reusing** `this.request`, so i needed to clear the old `this.request`. Thanks.

Comment: "clear" implies `this.request.property=...` you'd just `this.request = { some new object }`

Comment: True, but i'm using a **request interface** so Typescript obliges me to declare each property. So i write `this.request = { re-define each property }`